# Is it possible to download OSX updates

Tags: snow-leopard, software-update

I'm helping a friend update her iMac's OSX from 10.6.8 to the latest available for the hardware. That would be easy, if it weren't that the computer has only a 56k connection to the Internet, and so downloading updates would be unfeasible (and ridiculously costly). I don't have access to any other machine running OSX, only Windows and Linux. Also, I only have an unlimited internet connection at work, so physically bringing the computer there is not an option.

The computer is an iMac10,1, Intel Core 2 Duo @ 3,06 GHz, 4 GB RAM.

What are my options?

Comment: ouch. App Store login is necessary for all OS updates; which can only be done from a Mac. Unless previously 'purchased' the only OS available from the store is Yosemite, assuming the machine can run it [we'd need to know what machine/year etc] The only alternatives would be a less-than secure torrent/usenet download, with its attendant trust issues, or a friend with the installer on USB key/DVD etc

Comment: Can you expand on the "friend" point? I might be able to ask someone. Also, no torrent at work, but thanks for giving it a shot. Will edit with hw details

Comment: You'd need someone on a Mac with current access to the App Store to download the 'Install OS X Mavericks/Yosemite' application & drop it to a USB key for you. If they previously 'purchased' an OS they can re-download it from their purchase history. If not, Yosemite is the only one currently available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately the iMac can run Yosemite, the latest version of OS X. The only option you have is that find someone with a App Store account and ask him/her to get the OS for you as it's free to download for Mac users. Then make it bootable.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the latest combo-update for Snow Leopard (10.6.8) [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1399).

Comment: I want to update to something more recent, but thanks for the link